# How do I get my wire name to show up when using dynamic indexing?

Tags: chisel

When running something like

```
class Foo extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(Vec(4, Bool()))
    val idx = Input(UInt(2.W))
    val en = Input(Bool())
    val out = Output(Bool())
  })

  val x = io.in(io.idx)
  val y = x && io.en
  io.out := y
}
```

The generated Verilog loses the `x` name:

```
module Foo(
  input        clock,
  input        reset,
  input        io_in_0,
  input        io_in_1,
  input        io_in_2,
  input        io_in_3,
  input  [1:0] io_idx,
  input        io_en,
  output       io_out
);
  wire  _GEN_1; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  wire  _GEN_2; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  wire  _GEN_3; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  assign _GEN_1 = 2'h1 == io_idx ? io_in_1 : io_in_0; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  assign _GEN_2 = 2'h2 == io_idx ? io_in_2 : _GEN_1; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  assign _GEN_3 = 2'h3 == io_idx ? io_in_3 : _GEN_2; // @[main.scala 15:13]
  assign io_out = _GEN_3 & io_en; // @[main.scala 16:10]
endmodule
```

How can I make sure the wire name shows up?

Answer (score 3):

This can be worked around by creating a wire and connecting the dynamic index to the wire:

```
val x = WireInit(io.in(io.idx))
```

Which should return:

```
module Foo(
  input        clock,
  input        reset,
  input        io_in_0,
  input        io_in_1,
  input        io_in_2,
  input        io_in_3,
  input  [1:0] io_idx,
  input        io_en,
  output       io_out
);
  wire  _GEN_1;
  wire  _GEN_2;
  wire  x;
  assign _GEN_1 = 2'h1 == io_idx ? io_in_1 : io_in_0;
  assign _GEN_2 = 2'h2 == io_idx ? io_in_2 : _GEN_1;
  assign x = 2'h3 == io_idx ? io_in_3 : _GEN_2;
  assign io_out = x & io_en; // @[main.scala 16:10]
endmodule
```